# Cant figure out how to solve exception in java program

Tags: java, printwriter

The end goal is to create a program that reads a text file and then determines the lowest, highest, and average of all the numbers in the text file. My program has no errors, but upon running it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at PrintWriter.main(PrintWriter.java:40)
```

My code is below. If anyone could help me figure this out it would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class PrintWriter 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you wish to open");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();  
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String[] numbers = new String[100];
    int index = 0, count = 0, average = 0, total = 0;
    String regex = "[0-9]+";

            //Open and read text file
     try
     {
         inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
     }
     catch(FileNotFoundException e)
     {
         System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
         System.exit(0);
     }
     while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
     {
         String line = inputStream.nextLine();
         numbers[index] = line;
         index++;
         count++;
     }
     int lowest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
     int highest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
     for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
     {

         if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]) <= lowest)
         {
             lowest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]);
         }
         else if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]) >= highest)
         {
             highest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]);
         }

         total = total + Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]);
         count++;
     }
     average = Math.round(total / count);

     System.out.println("\nThe average of all the numbers is " + average + ". The lowest number was " + lowest + ". The highest number was " + highest);
     System.out.println("\nThe numbers are listed below");
     for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index ++)
     {
         if (numbers[index].matches(regex));
         {
             System.out.println(numbers[index]);
         }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 40? Have you tried using a debugger to single-step the program and check your logic?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(numbers[index])` is trying to parse something that isnt a number, please attach your text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you initialized your array to 100 elements and your loop iterates through all the array values (for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)), at some point, you will be trying to parse null values which causes the exception. So the loop should iterate until count and not array length. You don't have to increment count inside the for loop as you already have counted all the elements in the previous while loop. Also, you don't have to call Integer.parseInt 5 times in the loop, just get that integer once and store it in an int variable, then reuse the variable:

```
for (index = 0; index < count; index++) {
  int value = Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]);
  if (value < lowest) {
       lowest = value;
  } else if (value > highest) {
       highest = value;
  }

  total = total + value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of your Strings **MAY** not contain a parsable integer. Probably, they may contain whitespaces. So use `trim` method to get rid of that.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> public String trim()
>
> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and
>   trailing whitespace omitted.

Change this part of code

```
     int lowest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
     int highest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
     for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
     {

         if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[index].trim()) <= lowest)
         {
             lowest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[index].trim());
         }
         else if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[index].trim()) >= highest)
         {
             highest = Integer.parseInt(numbers[index].trim());
         }

         total = total + Integer.parseInt(numbers[index].trim());
         count++;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your text file contains a line that isn't a number (has spaces or letters), or you don't have 100 numbers in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't specify, how many numbers it holds. Due to this, only a part of the array is filled with strings from the file. These are parsed correctly. But at some point the code reaches the part of the array that isn't filled with lines. And then this call happens: `Integer.parseInt(someString)`, where `someString` is `null`, causing the `NullPointerException`. To fix this you could either add a counter for read lines and use this counter instead of `numbers.length`, or check if the `String` is `null` before parsing an `Integer` from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String line="";
        ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        String[] numbers = new String[100];
        int index = 0, count = 0, average = 0, total = 0;
        String regex = "[0-9]+";

        // Open and read text file
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File("filename"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file "
                    + "filename");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            numbers[index] = line;
            index++;
            count++;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);

            while (m.find()) { 
                int n =Integer.parseInt(m.group()); 
                System.out.println(n);
                arl.add(n);

            }
        }

        Collections.sort(arl);
        System.out.println(arl);
        int lowest = arl.get(0);
        int highest = arl.get(arl.size()-1);
        System.out.println("Lowest is: " + lowest );
        System.out.println("highest is: " + highest );
        total =  arl.size();

        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer mark : arl) {
            sum += mark;
        }
        int avg = sum /arl.size();
        average = Math.round(total / count);

        System.out.println("\nThe average of all the numbers is " + avg
                + ". The lowest number was " + lowest
                + ". The highest number was " + highest);
        System.out.println("\nThe numbers are listed below");

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use arrayList as they are dynamic. Your program has lots of unused memory!!